# How can I apply separate permission for each user of same group in samba (Ubuntu 11.04)?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, samba

I have created a group named Readers and added three users readera,readerb,readerc. The share folder created like /home/Readers/readera,/home/Readers/readerb and /home/Readers/readerc. Here how can I force all the user to view only their folders not others??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using standard Unix permissions – `chmod -R go-rwx /home/Readers/reader*` to remove group/world access.